# Don't insert duplicates with RepositoryRestResource

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

I have my repository class which exposes REST interface

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "user", path = "user")
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {

}
```

I want to avoid inserting duplicate objects via POST requests.

I protected my database with constraints and now it's OK on DB side. But there are exceptions in log file on every attempt to insert duplicate objects.

I can implement a controller where I manage POST requests and do necessary checks by myself.

But for me it's a pretty common task which may already be implemented in Spring.

What is the canonical and simple way to avoid duplicates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create and register a 'before create' Application Event listener as detailed in the manual:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#events

```
@RepositoryEventHandler 
public class UserEventHandler {

  @Autowired
  private UserRepository repository;

  @HandleBeforeCreate
  public void handleUserCreate(User user) {
    //check database

    if(duplicate){
       throw new DuplicateUserException(user);
    }
  }
}
```

You can register a `@ControllerAdvice` to return some meaningful response. For example:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlingAdvice{

    @ExceptionHandler(DuplicateUserException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, Object>
           handleDuplicateUserException(DuplicateUserException exception){

        Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        map.put("duplicateUser", exception.getUser().getUserName());

        return map;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I came to this solution as well (EventHandler).